# How to store struct information on a uint64_t for Game Center challenges

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center

I'm trying to store some game related information on the uint64_t context property of GKScore - to create a better gaming experience with the new Game Center Challenges. However, I'm not getting it right. I built a struct like below:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int gameMode;
    unsigned int destroyed;
    unsigned int duration;
} GameInfo;
```

I try the following:

```
uint64_t myContext

GameInfo info;
info.gameMode = 2;
info.destroyed = 50;
info.duration = 100;

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&info length:sizeof(info)];
[data getBytes:&myContext length:sizeof(myContext)];
```

to pack the struct to a NSData and then write the bytes to myContext.

Then, I try to recreate the information using the 64bit integer as follows:

```
NSData *newData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myContext length:sizeof(myContext)];

GameInfo *result = (GameInfo*) [newData bytes];
```

however, when I log out the values, I see that I'm only able to capture the first two values (gameMode and destroyed). If I add more variables to the struct, I still only capture the first 2 variables.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pack 96 bits of data (3 `unsigned int`s on iOS / ARM) into a 64 bit container. So you see the first two 32-bit values and not the third.

Maybe you could try using `short`s or `char`s, depending on the range of values your struct will hold, and try to get the stuct's size down to < 64 bits. I think 3 `char` on ARM will get aligned out to 48 bits (might be wrong about that if so please let me know!). So maybe use `short` anyway.

EDIT: example of possible way to change your struct, assuming you'll only store 16-bit values in each field:

```
typedef struct{
    uint16_t gameMode;
    uint16_t destroyed;
    uint16_t duration;
} GameInfo;
```